# JQuery - Return Value of Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using asp.net and its html helpers. The HTML.CheckBoxFor helper returns a check box Element like the one bellow.

```
<input data-val="true" 
    data-val-required="The isNewlyEnrolled field is required." 
    id="isNewlyEnrolled" 
    name="isNewlyEnrolled" 
    type="checkbox" 
    value="true" />

<input name="isNewlyEnrolled" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

The second input is used for submit purposes. Using JQuery I would like to return only the current or new value when the relative check box is clicked. However this is proving to be difficult.

Here is my code:

```
@model MapBuilder2_0.Models.MapLayers
<h1>Map Layers</h1>
<p>Select the layers to be included on the <b>map</b>. All are selected by default.</p>
<div class="btn-group" id="map-layers-btn">
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
    Layer1
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MapLayer01)   
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
    Layer 2
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MapLayer02)   
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
    Layer 3
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MapLayer03)   
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
    Layer 4
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MapLayer04)   
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
    Layer 5
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MapLayer05)   
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
    Layer 6
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MapLayer06)   
</label>
```

How can i return the appropriate value to indicate the check box selection each time it is clicked?

I've attempted to select the values using the bellow jquery but i think the fact that there is two inputs with the same name is problematic. It is doing two things i cannot understand. 1) it returns two values (im assuming one for each input) and 2) it does not change to reflect weather it is selected or not. it only returns the initial true value.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#map-layers-btn").children("label").on('click', function () {
        var child = $(this).children("input");
        var child_val = child.attr("value");

        alert(child_vala);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the checkbox value in jQuery you need [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

For the double element problem you can give your helper a class and only the main `<input>` will receive this class.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MapLayer1, new { @class="mapchk" })
```

Making your click handler simpler and registered *only* for the primary input.

```
$(".mapchk").on("click", function(e) {
    var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
    console.log(isChecked);
});
```